# Linux C++ GUI programming tool

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface

I want to build a very simple GUI based application in linux, c++. Which tool is good for it.
I have done programming in visual studio's windows form applications, so something close to that would be great.

Comment: @VJovic agree, but it seems to be a bit complicated to build GUI application with these instruments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend QtCreator and QtSDK by Nokia.

http://qt.nokia.com/products/qt-sdk/

Edit 2020:
Links changed, as produce moved several companies: https://www.qt.io/download

Comment: Totally agree. And without much effort the code will work on Windows, Linux and Mac OSX.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you have two majors graphical toolkit available :

- qt, made in C++
- gtk+, made in C

They both have bindings in lots of scripting language. But since you want to use C++, I guess that Qt can be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use [kdevelop](http://kdevelop.org). My experience is that it has the best code parser and code auto-completition for linux.

For GUI library, you can pick one of many (gtk, qt, ultimate, etc).